# Outgoing ip using ACI in a VNET

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'm using the ACI in a private VNET. My problem is, the outgoing ip from this container is not my public IP used in Azure Gateway, is some random ip.
There's some way to fix somehow this outgoing ip from some container using ACI?
OBS: I tested with a public container, I had a public ip to incoming, but for outgoing was different :|

Thanks!

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Is there any reason that you do not return the messages if the answer solves your problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, when you create the ACI in the VNET, you just can access the resources inside the VNET and the outgoing IP is a private IP of the VNET, so the IP is static if you do not delete the ACI.

When you create a public ACI, it can access the Internet. This time, as I think, the ACI has two public IP, one is the public IP or the FQDN of the ACI to access from the Internet. And another is the public IP of the host machine that the ACI deploy in. When you access the ACI from the Internet, you need to use the public IP or the FQDN which Azure provide you. But when you access the Internet inside the ACI, the outgoing IP is the host machine's public IP. You cannot decide which host machine you can use, so does public IP of the host machine.

If you need to decide the outgoing IP and must be a static one. You can install the docker server in the VM with a static public IP, then create containers in the VM. Then the outgoing IP is the public IP of the VM.

Or you can use the AKS, create the pod and associated with a service that uses the Load Balancer type. Then the outgoing IP is also static and it's the service public IP.